# problem getting foreign key value to display to display in resources

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I trying to build an CRUD Restful API with laravel. I encounter a problem whereby when I update an variable in my database, the value in the database changed, because I past the value into a resource file. it encounter a problem where by the query seem to be wrong.

This is my database ERD:
[image]

The database is whereby one variation_types example: "Size" has many variation_options like "Small, Large". Below are the models
Variation_types:

```php
    public function type()
    {

        return $this->belongsTo(VariationOption::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
```

Variation_options:

```php
    public function VariationTypes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VariationType::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note: This answers the original version of question where mappings were incorrect check edit history of question**

Your mapping looks incorrect becuase VariationType has many VariationOptions so in this case your mappings should be

```
class VariationType extends  Model
{
 
    public function variations()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(VariationType::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
}


class VariationOption extends Model
{
    public function type()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(VariationOption::class, 'id', 'type_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: after doing this i have an error saying  "message": "Trying to get property 'type_id' of non-object",

Comment: and now when I want to "GET" my data from my database the name which in variation types return "Name": null,

Comment: @LeeSoonFatt  After doing this you need to adjust your code accordingly like your mappings are now updated so if you were using them in your code you need to refactor it, the above is the key error that you were facing previously

Comment: Ya thanks alot i got that part to work, i think now the power i facing is if (isset($data['type_id'])) {
            $option->VariationTypes()->get(['type_id']);
        }

Comment: i having error getting the variable from my variation types

Comment: @LeeSoonFatt there is no `type_id` in your variation type model, now it should be `$option->VariationTypes()->get(['id']);` also do correct names of your method like there is on each option has one type_id so the relation name should be `type()` as shown in my answer or `variationType()` don;t use plural word if it has singular value. that is why I was asking that refactor your code as per new mappings

Answer (score 1):

You must place the other columns of the VariationType table in the variable `$fillable` of the model.

Comment: So what you mean is that i should place my $fillable in my variationOption into my VariationType?