# Laravel Api Resource User name get only

Tags: php, rest, laravel-9

```
public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_by_id' => $this->created_by_id ? $this->created_by_id : 'N/A',
            'updated_by_id' => $this->updated_by_id ? $this->updated_by_id : 'N/A',
            'blog_category_id' => $this->blog_category_id ? $this->blog_category_id : 'N/A',
            'title' => $this->title,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'desc' => $this->desc,
        ];
    }
```

this is my api resource here i want to get the user name in created and updated part . what will be efficient way to get the name only.

Comment: does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65900712/problem-getting-foreign-key-value-to-display-to-display-in-resources?

Comment: i have tried this but shows error

Comment: I found the answer here it is

`       return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'created_by_id' => $this->created_by_id ? User::where( 'id', $this->created_by_id )->first()->first_name . ' ' . User::where( 'id', $this->created_by_id )->first()->last_name : 'N/A',
            'blog_category_id' => $this->blog_category_id ?  BlogCategory::where( 'id', $this->blog_category_id )->first()->name : 'N/A',
            'title' => $this->title,
            'status' => $this->status,
            'image' => $this->image,
            'desc' => $this->desc,
        ];

Comment: that's one way of doing it.